# Complex queries in SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: sql-server-2005, constraints

I have a table in my database in which records conceptually can be children of other rcords. The table has a non-null name field. I need to ensure that each name in a set of children is unique, but not across the entire database. I'd like to enforce this using a constraint inside the Database. What's the best way to accomplish this?
I know that I am going to have to do a query at some point in the process like this:

```
@NameParameter NVARCHAR(512)
Select Name from MyTable
WHERE Name=@NameParameter
```

The question is where do I put this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not be understanding your question correctly, but my suggestion is to create another column that references the parent record of the child.  You could then create a A multiple-column index based on those  two columns to speed up any queries that reference these columns together in a where clause...  Thus your uniqueness would come from {parent_name, child_name}.  A constraint on these two columns would act as a key for that table, and not allow duplicates.

```
@childname NVARCHAR(255), @parentname NVARCHAR(255)
SELECT * FROM [child_records] 
WHERE [parent_name] = @parentname 
AND [child_name] = @childname
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I believe this should go into a "Instead of trigger". This [link](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6113179.html) provides a good example.